# Finding if a differential equation has a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Here is another problem which I don't have solution as well as idea

Consider the differential equation
$$
y''(x) + P(x)y'(x) + Q(x)y(x) = 0
$$
then set of initial conditions for which above differential equation has no solution is :

$$
y(0)=2 \mbox{ and } y'(0)=1 \\
y(1)=0 \mbox{ and } y'(1)=1 \\
y(1)=1 \mbox{ and } y'(1)=0 \\
y(2)=1 \mbox{ and } y'(2)=2
$$

according to me all above satisfy existence theorem but I don't know what to do as 1 option is correct and why ?

Comment: @mvw thanks you r  right . can u guide me on how u did that ?

Comment: You're not given any information on $P$ and/or $Q$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson well no . i stated the question exactly as it is in my textbook

Comment: If there's no condition on $P$ and $Q$ then they could, for example, both be zero, and you're looking at $y''=0$, so $y=ax+b$ and you are being given the slope and intercept of a stright line. Seems all the options are possible. Question doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  if P,Q are cts functions and not equal to zero then how to do this ?

Comment: I find it hard to believe the problem has a solution. If $P$ and $Q$ are constant, for example, you can explicitly solve the equation, and I don't see why you can't satisfy any of those initial value conditions.

Comment: It is strange to have detailed conditions, but rather unspecified $P$ and $Q$ otherwise. I could only attempt a matrix solution, where the conditions would provide the start vector, but without knowing $P$ and $Q$ looking at the exponential of the matrix would give not much insight, as too much would be possible.